# ASP Menu, problems adding submenu

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

I am testing out a menu, it is populated from the DB. It works ok until I add another sub menu under the previous sub menu.

This is the date, the issue is which adding number 8 as a sub menu to number 6

```
ID      MenuName    MenuLoc ParentID
1   ParentItem1       NULL  0
2   ParentItem2       NULL  0
3   ParentItem3       NULL  0
4   SubMenuItem1      NULL  1
5   SubMenuItem2      NULL  1
6   SubMenuItem3      NULL  2
8   Sub               NULL  6
```

Here is the code:

```
 private void getMenu()
      {
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Portal"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("Menu_Test", conn);

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

            da.Fill(ds);


            dt = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        DataRow[] drowpar = dt.Select("ParentID=" + 0);

        foreach (DataRow dr in drowpar)
        {
            menuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(),
                    dr["ID"].ToString(), "",
                    dr["MenuLocation"].ToString()));
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentID >" + 0))
        {
            MenuItem mnu = new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), dr["ID"].ToString(),        "", dr["MenuLocation"].ToString());
            menuBar.FindItem(dr["ParentID"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(mnu);


        }
    }
```

The code is crashing on the line:  menuBar.FindItem(dr["ParentID"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(mnu); with object not set to instance.

Comment: Sorry but the table won't display properly outside edit mode for some reason.

Comment: You are using a menuBar, but I don't see it declared in your code anywhere. Is it a global that exists outside the function? If not, that will throw the error you are getting.

Comment: it's declared in the web form